How can I upload complete Siemens Simatic S7-300 PLC station with Step7 Command Interface libraries?
I am using the Siemens Simatic Step7 Command Interface libraries S7HCOM_XLib and SimaticLib in my project for uploading a station from a S7-300 PLC with following code:
I get a compiling Error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
at the marked line.It is clear for me that the types are not maching, but I find no other way to add a IS7Project3 type project because S7ProjectType has no definition like "S7Project3"?
I am sure that I have the correct dll's.
    public void Upload_Station()
    {
        try
        {
            int retcode = 0;                
            ISimatic3 S = new Simatic();                
            IS7Project3 Pro;            
            Pro = S.Projects.Add("Test1", "C:\\temp", S7ProjectType.S7Project); //Add new Project "Test1" in the given path  ***Error
            Pro.UploadStation(retcode);             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText((@"C:\temp\log.txt")))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Error: " + ex + " " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }
    }


First of all: Use a decent logging framework. You'll appreciate it at some time in the future. Secondly: Please share the complete exception.

Sorry, I meant compiler error message and information.

Can you lay out how those types are related to one another? I am not familiar with those libs, but I figure you'd probably simply need a cast like Pro = (IS7Project3) S.Projects.Add(...); - have you even tried that?

@Fildor  You are great! Yes that was the solution. Thank you so much.

What I suggested is basically referred to by "An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" in the error message :D. So, if you come across it again: check if it's similar to this. It won't always be, though.
